# How to store the order of items when using shuffle method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built an online examination app. I have some models like:

- **Question** has many answers
- **Answer** belongs to question
- **Exam**

I built the form for user can do exam using `form_tag`. Currently, I used this code to shuffle the order of question's answers in exam **in the view**:

```
<% question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer| %>
...
<% end %>
```

With above code, every time exam was showed, it had the different order of answers. Now I want to store the order of answers, so I can review exam later. I'm thinking of creating another model to store the order, but I don't know how to get the order from **shuffle** method.

So I want to ask a way to store the order of answers **in an exam** that will help me can review the question with right order of answers in exam which user taken. Can someone give me an idea or solution?

**Update the model to store user's answers**

```
class ExamAnswer
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

This model has columns: exam_id, question_id, user_answer_id

Comment: What is your model which store the answer of the user for the corresponding question ?

Comment: @ThomasRuiz okay, I updated that model. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in app/models/question.rb
def answers_ordered(current_user)
  answers_ordered = question.answers.shuffle
  exam_answer = self.exam_answers.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :question_id => self.id, :exam_id => self.exam_id).first
  if exam_answer.nil?
    exam_answer.user_id = current_user.id
    exam_answer.question_id = self.id
    exam_answer.exam_id = self.exam_id
  end
  exam_answer.order_answers = answers_ordered.map{&:id} # add .join(';') if your sgdb does not handle the Array type
  exam_answer.save
  answers_ordered
end

# in your app/models/exam_answer.rb
class ExamAnswer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer

  # add the field order_answers as type Array or String, depending of your SGBD
end

# in your view
<% question.answers_ordered(current_user).each do |answer| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And then, when you need the order, you can access it through `question.exam_answer.order_answers`. I think I'd do something like this. Delete what you don't need in the `answers_ordered` method.

Comment: I would like to store the order of answers in an exam, so I can review the exam later with right order of answers. I don't clear how your code do it.

Comment: When you review the exam, you have the model ExamAnswer which store the user's answer of each of your question. With the new field added, you are able to see the order by a simple `question.exam_answer.order_answers`, it is where this code stock it.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood. I want to store the order of answers of questions in exam, not the order of user's answers. The other thing, you defined a method `answers_ordered(current_user)` but when you used it `question.answers_ordered.each`, you did not pass a user object?

Comment: Yeah, I miss that thing in the view. I'm editing it. For the other thing. You agree that one Question have one ExamAnswer for each User, right ? So, ExamAnswer is the model where you can store anything about each Question for each Exam for each User. So you can store the order of the answers in that model, via the method answers_ordered I wrote.